# Does anyone know if its possible to append a json object in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, web-scraping

I can't work out if its possible to do this... I am currently getting this output

```
{"BUSINESS":[{"title":"Luling City Market"},{"image":"https://i1.ypcdn.com/blob/f714c6a156c8bb5fb93178c0b1c4bc038dd96ec9_150x150_crop.jpg"}]}{"BUSINESS":[{"title":"Barry's Pizza"},{"image":"https://i1.ypcdn.com/blob/3b90e6b5687f5edf98e1abf1e9f74ddaf8f90e1d_150x150_crop.jpg"}]}{"BUSINESS":[{"title":"Luling City Market"},{"image":"https://i2.ypcdn.com/blob/f714c6a156c8bb5fb93178c0b1c4bc038dd96ec9_150x150_crop.jpg"}]}
```

From:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var fs = require('fs');

async function scrapeProduct(url){
const file = fs.readFileSync('restaurants.json')

var scrapeTitle = '//*[@id="main-header"]/article/div/h1';
var scrapeImage = '//*[@id="main-header"]/article/a/img';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

const [el] = await page.$x(scrapeImage);
const src = await el.getProperty('src');
const image = await src.jsonValue();

const [el2] = await page.$x(scrapeTitle);
const txt = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
const title = await txt.jsonValue();

console.log({image, title});
var product = {
    'BUSINESS_TITLE' : [title],
    'BUSINESS_IMAGE' : [image]
}

if (file.length == 0){

    fs.writeFile('restaurants.json', JSON.stringify(product), (err) =>{
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; };
        console.log('Created File');
    })
}else{

    fs.appendFile('restaurants.json', JSON.stringify(product), (err) =>{
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; };
        console.log('Updated File');
    })
}

browser.close();
}

var urls = [
'https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/mip/luling-city-market-1615603?lid=1000597596315',
'https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/mip/barrys-pizza-472089383?lid=1001593326336'
]

for(var val in urls){
    scrapeProduct(urls[val]);
}
```

Of which is not the right way to format a JSON file...

To ensure that it formatted correctly, it should be more like this:

{"BUSINESS-TITLE":["1","2"],"BUSINESS-IMAGE":["1","2"]}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append you can do first `JSON.parse(file)`  then update the content with the new product and finally
`fs.writeFile('restaurants.json', JSON.stringify(updatedProducts))`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and valid way of doing this would be in three steps:

Step 1: Parsing the json file to an array.

Step 2: Appending the object to that array.

Step 3: Stringifying and saving that to your file.

Comment: Hey, thank you for that. It seems to be working, however on the second iteration it is replacing the first append, any clue why?

Comment: @DanielArmstrong are you parsing the JSON inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, so it calls a loop for each 'URL' in an array. This calls upon a function in regards to the URL. - Everything within that function plays the part with JSON. So it Reads the file, extracts into an array. then appends and writes the file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DcyK2NWa <- Lines of code